# Mapleaflet- Latitude and longitudes are properly not getting plotted

Tags: python, leaflet, google-earth, matplotlib

I am using Leaflet (Mplleaflet) to plot and display a simple polygon of an area on a map. **I took the points, correctly, from Google Earth** but it is not plotting the coordinates on the city of Kolkata and around, which I did properly on Google Earth.
Here's that section of the code:

```
lats = [88.2221, 88.2111, 88.2749, 88.1833, 88.1530, 88.2221]
lons = [22.3645, 22.4757, 22.3357, 22.2653, 22.3142, 22.3645]
         
fig = plt.figure() 
plt.plot(lats, lons, 'red')         

mplleaflet.display(fig=fig)
```

I attached the screenshot.
[image: Comparison]

Answer (score 2):

Your plot from `mplleaflet` for the above coordinates is completely OK. Here is map with the same coordinates in JS Leaflet:

```
var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

var myGeojson = {"type":"FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type":"Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type":"Polygon",
        "coordinates":[[[88.2221,22.3645],[88.2111,22.4757],[88.2749,22.3357],[88.1833,22.2653],[88.1530,22.3142],[88.2221,22.3645]]]
      }
    }
  ]
};
L.geoJSON(myGeojson).addTo(map);

map.setView([22.3645, 88.2221], 10);
```

This is the result:

[image]

So coordinates are plotted OK.

What's not OK in your code is naming of coordinates. `lats` are actually longitudes and `lons` are latitudes, but this does not effect the plot. It seems that for some reason you didn't get the expected coordinates from Google Earth.

Answer (score 0):

As TomazicM says, the problem is the coordinates from Google Earh

For me the coordinates Google Earth (latitude, longitude) of these 2 points for example

[image]

are:

W point: 22.5351,88.2514 and not 22.3142 88.1530
E point: 22.4617,88.3079 and not 22.2653,88.1833

Result with Folium

[image]